# Firebase database is not a function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run isomorphic react app, using Firebase [functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/isomorphic-react-app/functions/firebase-database.js).
But can't get the firebase database and I get the error "firebase.database is not a function"

```
const firebase = require('firebase')

// Load the Firebase database module.
require('firebase/database')

// Initialize Firebase using a client-side config.
const firebaseConfig = require('./client/firebase-config.json')
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const getDb = (ref) => firebase.database().ref(ref)
// Error firebase.database is not a function
```

Modules versions:

```
"firebase": "^4.13.0",
"firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.2",
```

Comment: You should not have a dependency on the regular Firebase SDK in yoru node modules: `"firebase": "^4.13.0"`. Also you don't want to require the Firebase SDK in the index.json `const firebase = require('firebase')`, but instead require `firebase-admin`: `const firebase = require('firebase-admin')` or (more iditiomatic): `const admin = require('firebase-admin')`

Answer (score 1):

It works well with firebase-admin

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin')

const firebaseConfig = require('./client/firebase-config.json')
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const getDb = (ref) => firebase.database().ref(ref)
```